# Swift 3 didReceiveRemoteNotification is not working when application goes terminated

Tags: terminate

I am having problem in swift 3 FCM. Issue is that I am not getting FCM in app suspended(kill) state( here I am taking about data message from server not notification key but, by notification key it is working in kill state but pop coming along with that I really don't want to see). Other than that in app active state it is working fine, even in background state working pretty well but, as soon as I suspend(kill) the app I don't get any FCM after that. Here FCM not working means [didReceiveRemoteNotification] is not calling in app suspend(kill) state so If it won't call means we won't get FCM as well. So ultimately I am not getting FCM in app terminate.

I have search out on internet but everywhere talking about get fcm in background but in my case I want FCM in app terminate state( means app is not in app tray list as simple as that).

In app terminate state app also not connected to XCODE so I am unable to logs in app terminate as well. If you have any solution from above question please do let me know.

Thanks in advance for your interest in my question.